# CakePHP and jEditable display entire layout view when it is supposed to only return the value

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jeditable

I have setup in place editing in my CakePHP app, which works pretty good, except for one problem. When the data is successfully posted to database, the return value includes the entired 'admin.ctp' layout. I have tried a couple of things like `$this->autoRender = false` and `$this->layout = 'ajax'` without success. Please my code below:

jQuery Code

```
$('.setting_value').editable('/settings/ajax_edit',{
     id        : 'data[Setting][id]',
     name      : 'data[Setting][value]',
     select: true,
     type      : 'text',
     cancel    : 'Cancel',
     submit    : 'Save',
     tooltip   : 'Click to edit the title',
     indicator: '<img src="/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif">'
});
```

My Controller Function

```
public function ajax_edit(){
    // $this->autoRender = false; // this doesnt seem to work
    // $this->layout = 'ajax' // this does not work as well

    if ($this->request->data) {
        $this->Setting->id = $this->request->data['Setting']['id'];
        $this->Setting->saveField('value', $this->request->data['Setting']['value']);
        $this->set('newvalue', $this->request->data['Setting']['value']);
    }
}
```

Again, everythingn works great, but for when it returns the changed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trying out, I was able to figure it out. So I updated my function per the following:

```
public function ajax_edit(){
    $this->autoRender = false;

    if ($this->request->data) {
        $this->Setting->id = $this->request->data['Setting']['id'];
        $this->Setting->saveField('value', $this->request->data['Setting']['value']);
        return $this->request->data['Setting']['value'];
    }
}
```

Basically, I had to set autoRender=false and return the new value instead of using the view file to display. It now works as desired.